# Rate limiting to Azure VM

Tags: azure, rate-limiting, denial-of-service

Is there a way to add rate limiting to azure VM? We have a VM that generates images dynamically and a few users are abusing it by hitting the server hundreds of times at once. I implemented an application level check that stores the user's IP address along with the time and if the same IP made a request more than 5 times in the last minute, it will block the request.

It's helping but I don't like this solution and would prefer something that would block the user from even reaching the server to save resources.

Cloudflare has this feature but would prefer to just use azure instead and take advantage of the benefits Azure is currently offering us.

Comment: It may be possible with Azure Web Application Firewall, but I'm not sure if you can customise a rule exactly the way that you need. give it a try and let us know the result. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what platform your image generation service uses. That would help guide answers.

For example, if you're running ASP.NET, [request throttling was added in version 4.7.](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/throttle-concurrent-requests-per-session.md)

Answer (score -1):

You might use Azure Network Access Control List. Check - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-acl

Comment: I don't see any option to do rate limiting. Only option to block ips permanently.